# Vital information missing from Google Play Developer console crash reports

Tags: android

Many times I see exceptions in my Google Play Developer console which are missing some vital information.

For example the last crash I got in Google Play was :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2984)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3045)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1642)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:431)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate (Fragment.java:102)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState (FragmentManager.java:1952)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState (FragmentController.java:144)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:307)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:58)
  at be.gps.android73.activities.LanguageActivity.onCreate (LanguageActivity.java:23)
  at be.gps.android73.activities.main.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:117)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6956)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2927)
```

Now I was able to reproduce this crash in development. And in this case you get the same stacktrace, but with some vital extra information as you can see below

```
....
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
 Unable to instantiate fragment be.abc.cba.Abc
 make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
....
```

This *Unable to instantiate fragment be.abc.cba.Abc make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public* information is very handy when solving this issue.

I have seen this more than once that some info is missing in Goolge Play.
Is this normal ? Is there a way that Google Play does provide this information ?

Comment: yes, they are omitting the message from exceptions. If you switch to older reports it's possible to see them, so I wonder if it's just a drawback of using automatic collection. I hope not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked around for this. Got sent an answer from Google Vitals Team tech lead.

> It is a known issue and we're working on fixing it.

Sorry, I am not allowed to share dates or further details, but it's nice to know that it's a known issue and not forgotten.

Comment: Seeing this problem now and it's very frustrating, can you confirm you still see this too?

Comment: Apparently this was forgotten :(

Comment: It's been 5 years and this is still a thing. I'm also curious how it is possible to *accidentally* strip the exception message — it's a very specific, intentional action.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my personal experience, I understood that using Firebase Crashlytics can actually do this to your app. All the crashes get logged into crashlytics rather than the play console.